# Suse Linux - make test for mpfr says libgmp.so.10 can't be found

Tags: linux, gcc, gmp, suse, mpfr

I set up an ancient machine with SUSE Linux 10.1, and am trying to build a current distro of gcc, but that wants gmp, mprf and mpc.

Now, I installed gmp successfully, and I find it in /usr/local/include and /usr/local/lib.  I also find the shared library libgmp.so.10 in /usr/local/lib.  Alas, when I run make check for mpfr, it complains that it can not open the shared object file libgmp.so.10

The question, then, is what do I need to do to tell it where the shared object file is?

Thanks

Ted

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `/usr/local/lib` is on the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

Alternatively, configure mpfr with the `--with-gmp=/usr/local/` option. You'll have to do the same with mpc when you build that, but you'll have to also add the `--with-mpfr=/usr/local` option when configuring it.

Comment: but, in the mpfr directory, I ran "./configure --with-gmp=/usr/local", and the problem persists.  I knew about that flag and used it, which is why I am surprised at this error.  It happens at run time, not compile or link time.

Comment: If it's run-time, then it's because you don't have `/usr/local/lib` on your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. Try doing `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib make check` in the mpfr directory.

Comment: Be sure to export the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable in either the system bash profile or your own bash profile, otherwise you'll encounter the same problem when you try to run gcc. It's tedious to put that before every command you ever want to run using it.

Comment: OK, thanks.  Can you be merciful to an old programmer with no experience administering a Unix box, and tell me a) where to find the system bash profile, and if I would simply add a line that says "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib" to the end of it?  NB: This machine is mine, so I do have root access, but I don't know much about where stuff ought to be.

Comment: On new SuSE (12.1), there is a file `/etc/bash.bashrc` that has a message in the header about not changing it, you should change `/etc/bash.bashrc.local` instead. This file may not exist, if it doesn't, you can add it. Something similar should exist for 10.1, not entirely sure what it's called but it will be in the `/etc/` directory. You just put `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib` at the end of it and when users log in it should work. Any users already logged in won't see the change until they log in again.